# Javascript and HTML on Github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I would like to ask whether it is possible to host a website on Github pages with Javascript, HTML and CSS? I am confused with this because I when I search online, it states that Github pages is for static website and Javascript, as I know is a dynamic language.

Comment: Why not simply try that and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side JavaScript runs on the client and can be served from static files (which are supported by Github Pages).

It is server-side dynamism (including JavaScript via Node.js) that isn't supported by Github Pages.